# Zend with Symfony

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony1

There seems to have been [previous attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783336/symfony-zend-integration-blank-screen) to integrate Zend with Symfony in the same project. I hear it can be done and has been done, but aside from a slide show linked below, the actual video accompanying the slide show is not freely available.

So does anyone know of good resources that explain such integration well? blogs, videos, whatever. I'll add whatever you post here for easier access to others in the future.

Resources I've found so far:

- [this text slide show](http://www.slideshare.net/weierophinney/using-zend-framework-with-symfony)

> Edit: I should add if you've done this
>   yourself before, can you also please
>   post any tips (as little or lots) to
>   help those who may want to try it.

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons, but why do you want/need to do this?

Comment: @Pekka I'd like to use components from each. From what I know about Zend (been working with it for the past 2 weeks), it's possible to use Zend components in any project including plain PHP. But Zend is not perfect for my needs and I need more components some of which I've found readily available in Symfony (started learning Symfony now). This presentation I found suggests it's possible to combine the 2, but more how-to detail is what's really needed.

Comment: @jblue I see. Zend is very modular, so there shouldn't be any problems with using parts of Zend in a Symfony project. The only troubles you may run into is with the Autoloading, but that can also be turned off on the Zend end completely. You probably just won't be able to use any of Zend's MVC functionality together with Symfony: I expect that would be a doomed enterprise.

Comment: @Pekka, you're right. I was thinking to use Symfony as the base + Zend components as needed. So I will be using Symfony's folder structure but none of Zend's bootstrap and ini. Looks like this should be fine for a plan since I'm not sure how open Symfony is to being used as components-only in another project, while I know this is perfectly possible with Zend (zend components in another project).

Comment: @jblue from everything I read and from what little I have seen about Symfony, it is much less open to being used as a library than Zend is. Interested to see whether anything to the contrary comes up

Comment: @jblue re your last comment, yes. Using the model/view/controller mechanisms of two frameworks at once would probably be a catastrophe.

Comment: @jblue yeah. I'll add an answer based on this discussion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is completely simple to add the Zend framework to run in Symfony.  There are certain components of the Zend framework that compliment the Symfony framework.  I am currently using Zend for the Lucene Search, as well as their Mailer.

To use Zend in Symfony, you just need to do two things:

1. Copy the Zend framework to your /lib/vendor/ folder.
2. Modify the ProjectConfiguration file. (config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php)

   ```
     class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration 
     {
        static protected $zendLoaded = false;
        static public function registerZend()
        {
           if (self::$zendLoaded) { return; }
           set_include_path(sfConfig::get('sf_lib_dir').'/vendor'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
           require_once sfConfig::get('sf_lib_dir').'/vendor/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
           Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
           self::$zendLoaded = true;           
           }      
     }
   ```

All this can be found in the Symfony tutorial here:
http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/17

Answer (score 2):

From the discussion above:

> I was thinking to use Symfony as the base + Zend components as needed. So I will be using Symfony's folder structure but none of Zend's bootstrap and ini.

From my experience with ZF I would say, this can definitely be done and is worth simply getting started with.

You'll have to haggle with Autoloading a bit (you should probably load all Zend related includes manually and not use its autoloader at all) but other than that, I can't see any problems. (disclaimer: I don't know Symfony in depth at all and can't comment on possible namespace collisions, but seeing as Zend was built to avoid those, and Symfony is a mature framework, I don't think you'll encounter anything impossible.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Symfony as your top-level framework, it's trivial.

In fact, integrating a Zend Framework component even used to be part of the [standard symfony tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_2/Doctrine/en/16).

Comment: I didn't say anything about doctrine.  I'm talking about Zend_Mail, which he integrates down near the end.